# WPF - Combobox does not show selecteditem

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, combobox

Im new to WPF and VB and im having some trouble figuring out why the thing i select in a ComboBox dropdown does not show in the ComboBox after selection.

I have my ComboBox populated through bindings and DataContext. This is my Settings.xaml file

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabList">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ComboBox x:Name="tabs" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding tabList}"                                       
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TabList}" 
          Height="32" />
```

The views codebehind file (Settings.xaml.vb) then loads the ComboBoxes content in the class' constructor, and the data does show in the ComboBox

```
Public Class Settings

    Private loader As SettingsLoader

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Dim sh As New SettingsHandler(True)
        loader = New SettingsLoader
        loader.tabList = sh.Current.Tabs
        DataContext = loader
    End Sub
End Class
```

The SettingsLoader class looks like so. TRTab is my own class that simply inherits from TabItem and only adds a few extra properties, nothing fancy

```
Public Class SettingsLoader

    Private _tabs As List(Of TRTab)

    Public Property tabList() As List(Of TRTab)
        Get
            Return _tabs
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of TRTab))
            _tabs = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Do i need to add a property to my SettingsLoader that holds the selected item for the ComboBox to show or what am i missing ?

EDIT: Just to clarify what im trying to achieve: I have a TabControl with a number of tabs. Those tabs' Headers needs to be also shown in a ComboBox for selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because TabItem is a ContentControl the ComboBox will display its Content when the item is selected. You could confirm this yourself using the following XAML markup:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabList">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="tabs" Height="32"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TabList}">
        <TabItem Content="Content" Header="Header" />
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

When you open the dropdown, you will see "Header" but when you select the item and close the dropdown you will see "Content".

It generally doesn't make a whole much sense to set the ItemsSource property of a ComboBox to an IEnumerable of ContentControls. You could bind the ItemsSource to an IEnumerable(Of String) instead. Just add another property to your SettingsLoader class:

```
Public Class SettingsLoader
    Private _tabs As List(Of TRTab)

    Public Property tabList() As List(Of TRTab)
        Get
            Return _tabs
        End Get
        Set(value As List(Of TRTab))
            _tabs = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property tabHeaders() As IEnumerable(Of String)
        Get
            If _tabs Is Nothing Then
                Return Nothing
            End If
            Return _tabs.Select(Function(x) x.Header.ToString())
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

---

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TabList">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="tabs" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding tabHeaders}"                                       
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TabList}" 
          Height="32" />
</StackPanel>
```

The other option is to set the Content properties of your TRTab objects to the same values ass their Header properties.

Comment: Yes this seems to do the trick. Thanks for clarifying it also, it makes good sense to me. !